# Exclude values from same column depending on date, using Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I need to extract a set of IDs from a table using Hive. The table from which I am to extract the data is partitioned by date. What I need are distinct IDs that appear in the table eight days ago but are not in the table for dates that represent the last seven days. I have tried using a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM my_table
WHERE date = '2016-07-14'
  AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-07-15' AND '2016-07-21'
  );
```

However, I am getting an error message containing *Unsupported language features in query* (entire error message is too long to post here). Since I cannot use this approach in Hive SQL, what are my options here?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap first query into subquery? If this not help you can also try to replace NOT IN with LEFT JOIN + second_query.id is null

Comment: @leftjoin Not sure what you mean by "wrap first query into subquery". Care to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same functionality can be done using LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT a.ID 
FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID
        FROM my_table
        WHERE date = '2016-07-14'
        )a 
          LEFT JOIN (
                     SELECT DISTINCT ID
                     FROM my_table
                     WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-07-15' AND '2016-07-21'
                   ) s on a.ID=s.ID
WHERE s.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: It's usually helpful to add some comments with a answer explaining why it works

Comment: I have created similar table and tested that it works. When I ran it without modification on my environment it produced Unsupported SubQuery Expression exception...

Comment: I have tried to use this solution but I got *Unsupported language features in query* error again. However, I tried using the approach that uses `LEFT JOIN` mentioned in your comment and it works! If you change the answer to use this approach, I will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Please see my answer with LEFT JOIN instead of NOT IN